# Modify ip addresses in a socks capture pcap

Tags: pcap, socks

I have a pcap capture of socks traffic. The traffic goes like -

`client_ip <-> 127.0.0.1:9050 <-> destination_ip`

Looking at pcap in wireshark, thus, shows:

```
src_ip = 127.0.0.1 
dst_ip = 127.0.0.1
```

Is it possible to change src_ip and dst_ip addresses?

I tried bittwiste as:

```
bittwiste -I in.pcap -O out.pcap -T ip -p 6 -s 127.0.0.1,1.2.3.4 -d
127.0.0.1,4.3.2.1
```

But, only first packet gets modified. All packets from 2nd onwards remain the same.

I also tried tcprewrite as:

```
tcprewrite --seed=325 --infile=in.pcap --outfile=out.pcap
```

This changes all src_ip & dst_ip (127.0.0.1) to the same random IP, since it seems to find only one (same) endpoint IP.

How can I modify src & dst ip addresses in a socks traffic capture.?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR.** The `--endpoints` option of `tcprewrite` is what you're looking for. It requires a cachefile from `tcpprep`:

```
$ tcpprep --port --pcap=in.pcap --cachefile=in.cache
$ tcprewrite --cachefile=in.cache --endpoints=1.2.3.4:4.3.2.1  --infile=in.pcap --outfile=out.pcap
$
$ tshark -r out.pcap
1   0.000000     1.2.3.4 → 4.3.2.1     TCP 74 49870 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=43690 Len=0 MSS=65495 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=10438137 TSecr=0 WS=128
2   0.000030     4.3.2.1 → 1.2.3.4     TCP 74 80 → 49870 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=43690 Len=0 MSS=65495 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=10438137 TSecr=10438137 WS=128
3   0.000051     1.2.3.4 → 4.3.2.1     TCP 66 49870 → 80 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=43776 Len=0 TSval=10438137 TSecr=10438137
4   0.000101     1.2.3.4 → 4.3.2.1     HTTP 139 GET / HTTP/1.1 
5   0.000121     4.3.2.1 → 1.2.3.4     TCP 66 80 → 49870 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=74 Win=43776 Len=0 TSval=10438137 TSecr=10438137
6   0.023045     4.3.2.1 → 1.2.3.4     HTTP 11642 HTTP/1.1 200 OK  (text/html)
7   0.023094     1.2.3.4 → 4.3.2.1     TCP 66 49870 → 80 [ACK] Seq=74 Ack=11577 Win=174720 Len=0 TSval=10438143 TSecr=10438143
8   0.023517     1.2.3.4 → 4.3.2.1     TCP 66 49870 → 80 [FIN, ACK] Seq=74 Ack=11577 Win=174720 Len=0 TSval=10438143 TSecr=10438143
9   0.023547     4.3.2.1 → 1.2.3.4     TCP 66 80 → 49870 [FIN, ACK] Seq=11577 Ack=75 Win=43776 Len=0 TSval=10438143 TSecr=10438143
10   0.023560     1.2.3.4 → 4.3.2.1     TCP 66 49870 → 80 [ACK] Seq=75 Ack=11578 Win=174720 Len=0 TSval=10438143 TSecr=10438143
```

---

**Explanations**

According to [the documentation for `tcprewrite`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tcprewrite), `--endpoints=ip1:ip2` rewrites all packets to appear to be between ip1 and ip2. However, this option requires the `--cachefile` option.

The `tcpprep` cache file is used [to split traffic in two sides](http://tcpreplay.synfin.net/wiki/tcprewrite#RewritingSourceDestinationMACaddresses) depending on ports, IP addresses, MAC addresses, etc. Here, according to [the `tcpprep` wiki](http://tcpreplay.synfin.net/wiki/tcpprep#Port), we want to use the `--port` option.